# Detect Android pinch to zoom using JavaScript (besides Hammer.js)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, pinchzoom

In IOS I use the `$(window).resize()` event to detect a pinch to zoom action. 
I tried this in an Android device but it doesn't trigger.

I'm trying to determine if the user pinched to zoom by comparing the `"document.documentElement.clientWidth" and "window.innerWidth"`

Any ideas on what event to use if there is a change in the window size?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to the `gesturechange` event. This will allow you to detect the scaling ratio, and resize accordinly.

```
$(window).on('gesturechange', function(e){ 
     console.log(e) 
});.
```

The `e` wil contain all the information you need to know about the event, including the original scale size, and the current scale size, so you can resize and react accordingly.